# Checkmark in UITableView Cell

Tags: iphone, uitableview, checkbox, checkmark

I want Checkmark in particular TableView Cell.

So I have used code :

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

newRow = [indexPath row];
oldRow = [lastIndexPath row];

if (newRow != oldRow) {
    UITableViewCell *newCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    newCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

    UITableViewCell *oldCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: lastIndexPath]; 
    oldCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;

    lastIndexPath = indexPath; 
}
else{
    UITableViewCell *newCell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    newCell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;
    lastIndexPath = indexPath;
}}
```

Its working in iPhone Simulator fine.
But while testing in iPhone device, it crashes the application.

Any solution for this..?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is the crash error message?

Comment: EXE_BAD_ACCESS for oldRow = [lastIndexPath row];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely cause of your crash is in your ivar, `lastIndexPath`.  You're storing values in this without retaining them, so they may be released at any time.  Try defining a property named `lastIndexPath` (`retain` for manual reference counting, `strong` for automatic reference counting).  Then you can use `self.lastIndexPath = indexPath` or `[self setLastIndexPath:indexPath]`.

Also, it's bad to forcibly change a cell contents like this.  It's better to store the selected index, then reload the table data.  For maximum efficiency, only update the changed cells.  Have your `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method switch the checkmarks on and off.

Comment: Thanks. I have used as you suggested.
I have created property for lastIndexPath(NSIndexPath) and synthesize it.. And its working in simulator fine. But still problem in iPhone Device.

Comment: Are you using your new property fully?  Have you replaced `oldRow = [lastIndexPath row];` with `oldRow = [[self lastIndexPath] row];` and both cases of `lastIndexPath = indexPath;` with `[self setLastIndexPath:indexPath];`?

Comment: Can you edit your post to show the revised code, both of `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` and `didSelectRowAtIndexPath:`?  If it manages to identify the line that caused the crash, that would also be good to know.

Comment: Hey now got it solution without error.
I'll tell you after check in device.. Anyways thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Simply write following code in "cellForRowAtIndexPath" method.

```
[[cell imageView] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tickmarkBlue.png"]];
[[cell imageView] setHidden:YES]; 

if(<your condition here>)
{
      [[cell imageView] setHidden:NO];
}
```

Comment: Applying the changes in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is correct.  However, this doesn't directly address the original poster's crash problem.  Also, was this code written for some task that `[cell setAccessoryType:UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark]` wasn't suited to?